# How can I comfortably highlight PDF files without KDE?

Tags: software-rec, pdf

Okular is great but has many KDE dependencies. Xournal is not very suitable for highlighting. Evince doesn't have any "editing" functionality.

Comment: I don't know an answer to your question, but you may also ask at https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/

Comment: On side note, [this answer](http://askubuntu.com/a/11188/37165) on Ask Ubuntu had quoted [this link](http://blogs.igalia.com/carlosgc/2010/07/26/adding-new-annotations-with-evince/) that mentions future Evince releases might have highlighting feature. Current Evince only does text annotations.